# Sending HPGL-File to ancient HP Plotter via Serial interface from python wthout chiplotle

Tags: python

I struggle with getting chiplotle to run with python3. Is there a simple way of sending the plot?
`plot_hpgl_file` is all I was going to use from chiplotle. My plotter is an ancient HP 7575A, I am using a USB-Serial converter.

Answer (score 0):

The plotter uses rtscts, the following worked for me:

```
import serial
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file="test.hpgl"
    with open(file, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
    ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
                        timeout=5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=True)
    ser.write(content.encode())
    ser.flush()
    ser.close()
```